# Open view with object

Tags: ios, swift, object, init

I have a class with `tableView` and `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method. I created 2 objects to send to `init`. I want to change NSUSERDEFAULT by object. But my problem is: At the end of the method, how can I open another `view`?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let indexPath = indexPath.row
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(indexPath, forKey:"INDEX")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

    if(posicionSegmented() == 0){
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "CARTERAEMPRESAS")
        let ficha = FichaEmpresa(estadoSegmented: true)
    }else{
        let ficha = FichaEmpresa(estadoSegmented: false)
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(false, forKey: "CARTERAEMPRESAS")
    }

    //self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SegueFichaEmpresa", sender: self)
}
```

Thanks.

**EDIT**

I have to change view (and class) sending my bool.

Comment: What do you mean by opening another view ?

Comment: @Chajmz I have first view with UITableView and want open another view with some information

Comment: You have to create a segue in storyboard with identifier `SegueFichaEmpresa`

Comment: So by a view you mean another `ViewController` ? If this is what you want to do, did you implement the `prepareForSegue` method and add the segue identifier in your storyboard ?

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_storyboard/Chapters/StoryboardSegue.html

Comment: @Chajmz My bad, I dont need this method. I want go to another class and view sending my bool.

Comment: "I want go to another class and view sending my bool", but you don't want to open another ViewController, o_0 please explain yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First You have to assign an identifier to your segue.

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("youridentifier",sender: self)
```

Then

in

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "youridentifier" {
           let vc: NextViewControler = segue.destinationViewController
           vc.yourVar = ""
           //pass data
        }
    }
```

Comment: And how I receive in other class?

Comment: I Updated the answer you can pass data like that

Answer (score 0):

Here the error *'Receiver () has no segue with identifier 'SegueFichaEmpresa''* shows you dont have a segue identifier for a view controller.

Give **SegueFichaEmpresa** in identifier of that view controller. 
then call

```
 self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SegueFichaEmpresa", sender: self
```